# PostgreSQL Regular Expression identifying only special characters

Tags: regex, postgresql

I am trying to figure out how to identify any rows in a table that contains special characters but not spaces.

The reason is I am looking at data quality of a first name field and want to identify any rows that have special characters such as (-,.etc)

The below identifies almost what I need but also brings back names with spaces (Joel Smith) these should not be included.

```
SELECT
    first_name
FROM users
WHERE
    users.first_name ~* '[^a-z0-9]'
```

Many thanks in advance

Comment: What's the definition of a "special character"? Do you mean any character which is not alphanumeric or a space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Postgres regex doesn't seem to support negative lookaheads, which is one option we could have used here.  Instead, we may phrase your requirement for matching using this pattern:

```
^[^\- ]*[^\-a-z0-9 ][^\- ]*$
```

This says to match any number of non space/hyphen characters, followed by a single non alpha/space/hyphen character, followed again by any number of non space/hyphen characters.  This becomes the following in Postgres:

```
^[^\-[:space:]]*[^\-a-z0-9[:space:]][^\-[:space:]]*$
```

Here is a sample query:

```
WITH yourTable AS (
    SELECT 'abc' AS col UNION ALL
    SELECT 'abc  '  UNION ALL
    SELECT 'abc $'  UNION ALL
    SELECT 'abc$'   UNION ALL
    SELECT 'a-bc'   UNION ALL
    SELECT 'a-bc  ' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'a-bc $' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'a-bc$'
)

SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE col ~* '^[^\-[:space:]]*[^\-a-z0-9[:space:]][^\-[:space:]]*$';

abc$
```

### Demo

Comment: Thanks this seems to do what I need. The only other question is if I want to exclude any names with - in it. In my data set there are a lot of names like Jane-Ann but this would be a valid name. How can I amend the above to not include -?

Comment: Are you saying that `-` is a character you _want_ to appear in matches, or you _don't_ want it to appear?

Comment: Sorry, don't want to appear in matches.

Comment: Thanks that does the job!